# Is there a way to query Esri's map service rest endpoint but only get the bounding box of each feature (or a single feature)?

Tags: extents, arcgis-rest-api

I want to be able to zoom a user to a state of their choosing. But i don't want to load all of the vertices of each state. instead I want to query the rest endpoint and get the 4 bounding box coordinates for each state. Ideally, i would store those client side. Failing that, i would like to be able to query for the bb of a single state so i can zoom a user to that.

I am hitting against an ESRI ags 10.3.1 server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queryTask.executeForExtent(query, callback?, errback?)`

This is a method of the QueryTask class that returns the extent of the found features. This only works on ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 and later.

Here's ESRI's documentation on QueryTask: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#executeforextent

To send the query directly, append `&returnExtentOnly=true` to your outgoing query.

```
http://arcgisServer/arcgis/rest/services/myService/MapServer/0/query?f=json&returnExtentOnly=true
```

Comment: hummm. close but i'm not using esri js api. and that method is only valid on hosted services on arcgis.com and only after 10.3.1

Comment: Can you update your question with the server version you're using?

Comment: is anyone using the execute for extent method in the esri js api that can tell me the url it kicks out for the request? that is really all i need. but i don't see it listed in the rest api reference. If it was a change in the js api i would expect a corresponding addition in the rest api here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/query.html

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Answer updated!